# Salesforce angular security concern

Tags: security, security-review

We are using angular for front-end and Salesforce is being used for maintaining database. REST APIs have been written on Salesforce to communicate and fetch data to front-end. SSO OAth settings are also being used in Salesforce. This results in exposing queries on browser console. I need to know, how secure is this setup. Since Salesforce query calls are being exposed on browser-console, will the database become accessible with minimal efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are Sending querys with a Salesforce logged user. I think all is Ok.

[image]

If You are sending querys with an admin user, You are building an insecure applicattion
[image]

Comment: Yes, we are sending query through Custom profile's user. How is it going to be secured. I mean by looking into the query, will someone be able to login to database (i.e Salesforce) somehow.

Comment: I edit the answer with a picture. I hope this clarify you what can be secure and what can be insecure

Comment: +1 Nice explanation,  a picture is better than thousand words. @SalesforceLearner, With queries you need to handle security in apex to avoid SOQL injection, etc. Refer [Secure Coding Cross Site Scripting](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting)